# Some form checkbox combinations do not work

Tags: html, checkbox, modx

I have this code and can't figure out what seems to be the problem: if i select 1 & 2, 1 & 3 it's working. 
But if I select 2 or 3 only then it's not working.
What seems to be the problem?
I would like to select multiple at the same time.

i think I need to put some if and else here? 
But don't really know and sure how?

This is the code:

```
<div style="background-color:#CCDFED">
<form method="post" action="[~[*id*]~]">
   <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="registrationForm" />
    <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <label for="termine" style="margin:0.5em">Termine:</label>
     <td>
     <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="termine1" value="Montag 4. Oktober 2010"    eform="Termine::1"/>&#09;Montag 4. Oktober 2010 <br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="termine2" value="Mittwoch 13. Oktober 2010" />&#09;Mittwoch 13. Oktober 2010 <br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="termine3" value="Freitag 22. Oktober 2010"  />&#09;Freitag 22. Oktober 2010 <br/>           
     </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
      <td><label for="email" style="margin:0.5em">Email:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" size="60" maxlength="60" eform="Email:email:1" /><td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>
       <label style="margin:0.5em; display:block" for="kopieren" >Bitte kopieren Sie den Anti-Spam Code ein: </label>
       <img src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code" border="1" style="margin:0.5em"/></td>
     </td>
     <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="vericode" size="20" /> </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" valign="right">
         <input align="right" type="submit" name="submit" style="margin:0.5em" value="Register" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>    
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think problem is in your server script, not html.

Comment: what do you mean?i'm sorry it's all new to me, could you please be specific?thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's not working'?

Comment: @Lucas Heneks: if you will try my code, you can only select the 1st & 2nd, or 1st & 3rd. But if you select the 2nd or 3rd, then it's not working. That means, the selection will not appear

Comment: He means the HTML is functional(the code u posted) its the thing that is handling the input that is broken(which we can not see).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do... please explain in a little more detail. For starters... your first `<td>` is not closed, and neither is your `<table>`

Comment: add the code behind. this html tells us nothing.

Comment: @Nix:sorry about that.I can post the whole code

Comment: @ALL: the code is already in my edited post. I hope that helps

Comment: What is the server side language? What template engine?

Comment: The code that does stuff with the checkboxes is not here.  What software is running on the server to handle this page?

Comment: I just formatted all of it, @tintincute I added some missing td's make sure you have everything in your table properly enclosed in tds.  We are still mising the logic that is reading what is checked.    You said that if you try the code we can only select 1/2 or 1/3 we can select all of them?  So I am unsure on what type of problems you are having.

Comment: @ALL:try to go here:http://www.wikima4.com/index.php?id=361 and try to register.

Comment: @Oded:I'm using modx cms, that's an eform. Chunks hope you're familiar with it, coz I just started to learn this.you can go to the link that I posted

Comment: I can post the four codes that involves with these.

Comment: Using Chrome and it worked fine...Termine 1: Montag 4. Oktober 2010
Termine 2: Mittwoch 13. Oktober 2010
Termine 3: Freitag 22. Oktober 2010

Comment: @tintincute - you can have up to 5 tags for each question. Use them.

Comment: @Oded: what do you mean 5 Tags? What would I do?

Comment: @Nix: That's true it's working if you select the 3 dates, but if you select the 2nd date only (alone) or the 3rd date only (alone) or the 2nd date and 3rd date, then it will not work. you will not get any confirmation.

Comment: @ALL:please check the code i posted its edited already. I'm not sure if I did it right

Comment: I mean that when you ask a question, there is a **Tags** area under it. You can use up to 5 tags - the more you use the better.

Comment: @Oded:i see sorry about that. i saw it. ok i'll use it then.Have you tried the registering in the site?

Comment: I see what you are saying now, why do you not post back validation errors to the site?  To meet it appears that there is missing some type of dirty check for the 2nd or 3rd box.

Comment: @Nix: my bad, here is the error on the other form: Some errors were detected in your form:
Themen » Incorrect value

If you try the other form it will appear like this. But the other form, nothing happens

Comment: @Nix:where do you think is the problem? Is it the checkbox?

Comment: @Nix:where should I add the name"termine"[]"? only in the first form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making them required by setting eform on all of them.  Remove the ::1 eform if they are not required.  I also added a validation message.

Try:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="termine1" name="termine[]" value="Montag 4. Oktober 2010"    eform="Termine::1:Please select at least one box"/>&#09;Montag 4. Oktober 2010 <br/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="termine2" name="termine[]" value="Mittwoch 13. Oktober 2010" />&#09;Mittwoch 13. Oktober 2010 <br/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="termine3" name="termine[]" value="Freitag 22. Oktober 2010"  />&#09;Freitag 22. Oktober 2010 <br/>
```

I am doing all of this blindly, so bear with me.  Once you have submitted the form, you now need   I no longer see your code for the confirmation page.  All you need to change is in your report you need to use

```
[+termine+].
```

Comment: @Nix: yes i did that it is still the same:-(

Comment: I think you need to set the same name, and if its required keep ::1 if not remove it.  I also think u need to post some validation feedback back to the user.  Try the above code notice the addition of id and name.  Make sure you change your form code accordingly to use the new name="termine[]"

Comment: @Nix:I will try this sample & then will get back to you asap.

Comment: @Nix:by the way where should I change the new name="termine[]". You mean in the first form?

Comment: @Nix: hope you're still there, I tried the new code you gave me, but then if I select any dates, it will only display "Termine" but no dates available. hmmm don't you think we have to have different names in each forms?

Answer (score 0):

This might because of label is not attaching with your, checkbox, just provide Id to checkbox, please refer below

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="termine1" name="termine1" value="Montag 4. Oktober 2010" eform="Termine::1" />
        <label for="termine1">&#09;Montag 4. Oktober 2010</label>
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.